# Static files not appearing when going live django project

Tags: python, django

I have the correct settings to get static files live, but no static files work even though I do collectstatic

My Settings.py:

```
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')`
```

Debug is False

Answer (score 0):

Your settings.py file should contain the following lines of code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')`
```

Then you have to add the following codes in the project's main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
... # Your urls
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If everything is added properly as I have mentioned here then you have to run a command to collecting static files to a specific directory in your server.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then restart your server and browse your site. I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: didn't work  ://

Comment: Could you please try again with the following codes in your `settings.py` file: 
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]`

`MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`